# Splunk - Extracting from search results using regex and aggregates

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the following search:

```
my search | eval LINE=(MESSAGE) | where MESSAGE LIKE "Process : Hp:%" 
| stats values(DATETIME) as Date values(LINE) as Status
```

That search gets me the following result:

```
Date                                Status
2023-10-31          Process : Hp: N1 - NOEAST WorkId: 9 Numbers: 209 Cases: 224 Lines: 465         
2023-10-31          Process : Hp: N1 - NOEAST WorkId: 9 Numbers: 499 Cases: 577 Lines: 954         
2023-11-02          Process : Hp: N2 - NOEAST WorkId: 13 Numbers: 178 Cases: 230 Lines: 376         
2023-11-03          Process : Hp: N2 - NOEAST WorkId: 13 Numbers: 466 Cases: 497 Lines: 725         
2023-11-03          Process : Hp: O1 - SOWEST WorkId: 11 Numbers: 182 Cases: 275 Lines: 619
```

I need to go further in my extraction in order to get the following result:

```
HP                  Total Numbers     Total Cases     Total Lines
N1 - NOEAST 9          708             801              1419
N2 - NOEAST 13         644             727              1101
O1 - SOWEST 11         182             275               619
```

Is it possible to get my desired result using a subsearch and regex to get the index of the parts of the string that I have to add together? If so could someone give me an example to get started? Or is there a simpler way to do this all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the necessary fields by using the `rex` command with named capturing groups in your regex. Afterward, you can utilize the stats command to `sum` up the numbers, cases, and lines, grouping them by the HP field, which represents a combination of the `location` and the `WorkId`.

```
my search | where MESSAGE LIKE "Process : Hp:%"
| rex field=MESSAGE "Process : Hp: (?<HP>\w+\s-\s\w+)\sWorkId:\s(?<WorkId>\d+)\sNumbers:\s(?<Numbers>\d+)\sCases:\s(?<Cases>\d+)\sLines:\s(?<Lines>\d+)"
| stats sum(Numbers) as "Total Numbers", sum(Cases) as "Total Cases", sum(Lines) as "Total Lines" by HP, WorkId
| eval HP=HP." ".WorkId
| fields - WorkId
```